# What is Python sklearn predict function working principle

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn function. I am quite new on Python and I was using programming languages such as C++ or Java so I am little bit confused about working principle of predict() function. Here is an example :

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)
regressor = LinearRegression()
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
```

I understand this part of the code but after that to make a single prediction example continues like :

```
print(regressor.predict([[12]]))
```

I've read the working principle of predict() function scikit-learn document and it needs a parameter like 2d array or matrix. But in this example, coder didn't write what is the name of the array.
How does python knows to run the function for x_train array?

X_train dataset decribes yearsOfExperience data of employees so my second question is how does python knows with [12] to get data for employess with 12 yearsOfExperience? Isn't it something like index of array, isnt't it supposed to be 12th element of array?

Comment: `regressor.predict([[12]])` is presumably just to test what the model is predicting for the case when `X` has that value. But there's nothing more to it, nothing to do with `X_train`or `X_test`, this will output a single `y_pred`

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't make sense because you're not running the `fit` method.

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
plt.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'blue')
```

When you run the fit method, that updates/creates the weight that the model uses to make a prediction. Running the predict method alone, won't actually predict based on what it's learnt from the training data.

Think of the `fit` method as how the model learns.

Comment: So, when you use fit() method, it causes model to run predict() method with its latest run input?

Comment: When you use the fit method, it updates some internal variables that are later used by the predict method. Have a look at this article, https://letsfigureout.com/2021/01/05/simple-linear-regression-in-python/ it explains it in detail both how that algorithm works in detail as well as how its done with sklearn.

Comment: Thanks it is basically answer for my first question. By the way how does function knows with [[12]] it means data from that array which has value 12. Isnt it supposed to by index of element?

Comment: When you use the `predict` method you are essentially saying, here is some new data tell me what the target (Y) variable is going to be. That can either be a variable name, or it can be an object, think of it like an anonymous variable.

So you're passing the value of X and the predict model is going to predict what the value of y is and return that.

Comment: @trytobedeveloper here `12` is a value, not an index of any array; it would seem that your `X` is one-dimensional. For more details, please post a [mcve].

Comment: That was exacly what i was looking for. Thanks